# Can't activate broadcom driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I did a dual boot from Windows and I installed Ubuntu 18.04.
On the 'try version' from my usb I could 'apply changes' in the Software & Updates => Additional Drivers to select:

```
Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel source (prorietary)
```

Then my WiFi card worked and I could connect to the internet.
Now I installed the 'real' version on my disk, on when I want to do the same thing and 'apply changes' it simply going back to 'Do not use the device' button.

I don't have the possibility to get internet without my wifi card.

How can I debug/fix this?